# How to remove text shadow when print pdf using getSVG() in HighChart

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts

I have a stacked column chart, using getSVG() to get svg string and pdfMake to print pdf, and the the result is that the texts on the column have some weird shadow.
https://ibb.co/HrC62HP

I would like to know how to remove it,

This is the code to render the text, I'm using angular
https://ibb.co/XktZV2v

I've used replace method to change the stroke-width style to 0 in the svg string. It didn't work

Please help! Thank you.

Comment: Hi, instead of an image of the code please attache a block of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This configuration removes all shadows from dataLabels, change in `style.textOutline` to false when you don't want default text outline.

```
  exporting: {
    chartOptions: {
      plotOptions: {
        series: {
          color: 'rgb(124, 181, 236)',
          dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            inside: true,
            format: '{y} min <br>',
            style: {
              width: '60%',
              textOverflow: 'elilipsis',
              fontSize: 10,
              color: 'rgb(0, 0, 255)',
              textOutline: false
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tcj4q8vz/

Comment: Thanks for your response, I've tried your method but still It doesn't work. The problem only occurs when I print out PDF file.  May be It's pdfMake library's problem. I will try to replicate the problem on stackblitz.

Comment: It was actually my bad, I got 2 seperate chart options, one to render and the second to export. Thank you very much for your support! But still I have other problems.